# Issue with Form Validation in Django Project

Tags: python, django-forms

Description of the Problem:
Upon submitting the form in my place_order view, the form validation is not successful, and it redirects to the else block instead of the 'payments' page as intended. I've tried debugging this issue but haven't been able to identify the root cause.

Relevant Code:

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0,):
    current_user = request.user

    # if the cart count is zero or less than zero, then the user will be redirected to shop/store
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    cart_count = cart_items.count()
    if cart_count <= 0:
        return redirect('store')

    grand_total = 0
    tax = 0

    for cart_item in cart_items:
        total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
        quantity += cart_item.quantity  # Increment quantity inside the loop

    # Calculate tax and grand total outside the loop
    tax = (2 * total) / 100
    grand_total = total + tax

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # store all the billing information inside "Order" table
            data = Order()

            data.user = current_user
            data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
            data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
            data.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
            data.order_total = grand_total
            data.tax = tax
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.save()

            # generate order number
            yr = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y'))
            dt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%d'))
            mt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m'))
            d = datetime.date(yr, mt, dt)
            current_date = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")  # 20210305

            order_number = current_date + str(data.id)
            data.order_number = order_number
            data.save()

            # to get the order object
            order = Order.objects.get(
                user=current_user, is_ordered=False, order_number=order_number)
            context = {
                "order": order,
                "cart_items": cart_items,
                "total": total,
                "tax": tax,
                "grand_total": grand_total,
            }
            return render(request, "PixelCart/payments.html", context)
        else:
            # If form is not valid, handle it here
            return redirect("checkout")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check why the form is NOT valid, using `form.errors` and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I've thoroughly checked the form errors using `form.errors`, and I couldn't identify any issues on the template page.

Comment: Share form.errors in your original question so we can help